# Send email Transport Mandrill failed

Tags: php, email, cakephp, mandrill

I fought enough to be able to send an email from the API KEY Mandrill with a user it provides me if you have your account. I could find the answer and leave the answer here in case someone else serves.

[MandrillTransport](https://github.com/khanlou/MandrillTransport-CakePHP)

Config Mandrill in email.php

```
public $mandrill = array(
    'transport' => 'Mandrill',
    'uri' => 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/',
    'api_key' => 'YR3eo8WM9F-Je2********',
);
```

My code email :

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->config('mandrill'); 
$email->from('example@example.com');
$email->to('example2@example.com');
$email->subject('Subject for Email');
$result = $email->send('Here is some test content for the email.');
print_r($result);
```

Response :

```
[Mandrill] => Array
    (
        [status] => error
        [code] => -1
        [name] => Invalid_Key
        [message] => Invalid API key
    )
```

Under these circumstances you receive this error message (rare for me, since the api key is fine).

**EDIT**

I realized thanks to the example used instead of api_key key but only rough with change :

```
'api_key' to 'key' => $apikey,
```

Comment: The example on the github page uses ```key``` as key for the array. Not ```api_key```

Answer (score 0):

I realized thanks @César to the example used instead of api_key but key only rough with change in my config :

```
public $mandrill = array(
    'transport' => 'Mandrill',
    'uri' => 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/',
    'key' => 'YR3eo8WM9F-Je2********',
);
```